# Flutter:1.20.2 : Error launching application on iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: siangztang@gmail.com (APHJCKJCD5)"
Xcode build done.                                            4.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
Exited (sigterm)
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on iPhone.

Comment: Facing the same issue here.

Comment: have you updated the iPhone os ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for me the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package was causing the issue.

Bumping its version to `flutter_svg: ^0.18.0`  solved the issue.